# How do I run python in Codeanywhere?

Tags: python

I just started with learning Python 3.4.x.

I really want to keep learning and developing on all devices. That's why I'm using Codeanywhere. 
But the problem is I don't know how to execute a .py file in Codeanywhere.

Is there a method to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with codeanywhere. Have you looked into [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com)? This seems like it would suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for answering. 

Yes I already looked into Pythonanywhere but it doesn't have an Android app. Codeanywhere has an Android app.

Comment: Pythonanywhere is built on a web platform, so you should be able to use their webpage as an "app", although they state that their Android application is in beta, so I'm not sure how good it is.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- it's still in beta, but we have a big release tomorrow that significantly improves Android support :-)

Answer (score 2):

You run your .py files just like you would if you were running the python commandline in windows.

ex. 
python myfile.py

Open a SSH terminal from your python devbox and type it in the cmd line and you're all set.